# Append writer in same datfile in spring batch

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch

I'd like to know how to specify that I want the data output by the second job being appended to the data output by the first job:

> job1 ---> data 1 ---> Output TXT file
>
> job2 ---> data 2 ---> SAME Output TXT file

First writer

```
<bean id="writerCabeceraCatalogo"
    class="es.lacaixa.absis.batch.arch.internal.writer.AbsisFlatFileItemWriter"
    scope="step">
   <property name="name" value="writerContratoCompleto"></property> 
   <property name="resource">
<bean class="es.lacaixa.absis.batch.arch.internal.util.AbsisFileSystemResource">
   <constructor-arg ref="file_contrato"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Second writer

```
<bean id="writerContrato"
    class="es.lacaixa.absis.batch.arch.internal.writer.AbsisFlatFileItemWriter"
    scope="step">
<property name="name" value="writerContratoCompleto"></property> 
<property name="resource">
```

How can I configure this in spring batch. Thank you

Comment: `Invalid property 'appendAllowed' of bean class [es.lacaixa.absis.batch.arch.internal.writer.AbsisFlatFileItemWriter` Does this `AbsisFlatFileItemWriter` class provide a setter for `appendAllowed`? Please share its code to be able to help you.

Comment: thanks for answer. No in my class i dont have a setter for appendAllowed

Comment: So that's answers your question. Either add a setter for that property or make your writer extend `AbstractFileItemWriter` (or `FlatFileItemWriter`) which already has it.